# Changes not triggering workflow and jobs based on defined condition

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have following workflow configurations:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      changes:
        - /*script.yaml
    
variables:
  CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: $CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP
  ROOT_DIR: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
  SCRIPT_PATH: /etc/executable/scripts/
  A_REPOSITORY_SCRIPT_PATH: /folder/a/script.yaml
  B_REPOSITORY_SCRIPT_PATH: /folder/b/script.yaml


stages:
  - init

# A Workflow:  
deploycheck a 1/6:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - ${A_REPOSITORY_SCRIPT_PATH}
  stage: init
  script: |
    [ -f "${SCRIPT_PATH}/script.yaml" ] && cp -v "${SCRIPT_PATH}/script.yaml" ${SCRIPT_PATH}/SCRIPT_yaml_$CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP.txt

# B Workflow:    
deploycheck b 1/6:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - ${B_REPOSITORY_SCRIPT_PATH}
  stage: init
  script: |
    [ -f "${SCRIPT_PATH}/script.yaml" ] && cp -v "${SCRIPT_PATH}/script.yaml" ${SCRIPT_PATH}/SCRIPT_yaml_$CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP.txt
```

I want this workflow to trigger when a change is made to any `script.yaml` file anywhere inside the repository and pushed to `master` branch.

And once the workflow is triggers depending on the path and which `script.yaml` was changes respective jobs should run.

However, nothing happens with this and no matter which `script.yaml` I change this workflow never gets triggered.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your glob pattern would only match the root directory.

To match in any directory, use `"**/script.yaml"`

Comment: Thanks, i changed it. Now it triggers every time a pushed is made to a branch but still doesn't trigger on a push to `master`